# Whats the difference between "Software Version" and "Platform Version"?

Tags: blackberry, version

i read some post about platform-difference
but i can't solve my problem
i made network-program in bold9000 using 3G &wifi

in my bb9000
   **os version:5.0.0.509
   platform 5.2.0.50
   branding 1.0.114.308o**
it works very well

but when my customer tested it in bold9000
   **os v5.0.0.681
   platform 5.2.0.64
   branding version 1.0.1180.265t.** 
at that situation 
wifi works but 3G doesn't work
what's wrong with my phone ?

Every suggestion is appreciated
plz warm-answer  ㅠ ㅠ

Answer (score 1):

Software/App Version - Indicates the version of your applications (Address book, browser, calendar, also WiFi config wizard, etc.)
Platform/OS Version - Indicates your version of system software (Java base/core software, radio codes, etc.)

In what way doesn't the 3G not work? You can use 3G in calls? Is the .681 phone in the same infrastructure like the .509 phone? Possibly the one connects through BIS, one through BES?